# Analyze network traffic per port for network user

Tags: windows, networking, router, windows-8.1, pfsense

I have someone on my networks who plays a lot of online games and I want to prioritize his game packets so that he can stop complaining about the ever so evil "lag". He is on a Windows 8.1 Pro PC and I have a PFSense box connecting the whole network to the modem. I have thus far managed to fix his troubles by prioritizing everything coming from his PC but unfortunately now he gets priority even when he is doing something like watching YouTube and this is definitely not what I want.

I have tried looking up the ports most used by his games online but I cannot seem to find any info that works. I have decided that the best way to determine which ports to prioritize would merely be to monitor which ports on his PC carry the most traffic while he is playing his games. Unfortunately, after a whole day of research I could not find any way to achieve this on neither PFSense nor Windows. I can find ways to capture his packets but I cannot find something that will analyze these packets and give me traffic per port.

Comment: Wireshark can analyze traffic and do what you want. Apply the correct filters.

Comment: @ChrisinNL I do have Wireshark but I have no idea how to do this, could you possibly elaborate a bit?

Comment: This might get you started: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Answer (score 0):

You could simply prioritize his box as you already do, but only for UDP packages. Most online games will use UDP for time critical communication.